# Can a drop down menu have a flexible width?

Tags: css, navigation

I've built out a standard drop down menu (nothing fancy), however, in order to expand it I have to set a fixed width. Can I just leave out the width and have it expand based on the amount of content I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** yes.

**Long answer:** it depends quite a bit on how you've constructed the markup, what your CSS looks like, and whether you use something like jQuery for animating the dropdown. The CSS I used to use for dropdowns was a variation of Suckerfish and didn't need a fixed width, so it **is** possible. If you can post a simple example of what you're doing someone can likely make suggestions on how to eliminate the need for fixed widths.